# Avoiding special characters in url in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, special-characters

i have a treeview in that adding nodes dynamically and adding javscript click function on each node.. here thisFileNode.Value  have  url values,avoiding spl charcters in url i have used escape function  in my code.. still its not working ..
can anyone help me please

i dont familar with escape, what it actually does??? and how to work on that?

```
   thisFileNode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:clickNode(this, escape('" + thisFileNode.Value + "'));"
```

if any spl characters in the url it should deleted and how can i get the valid url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or alternatively, you may manually escape special characters:

```
thisFileNode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:clickNode(this, '" + HtmlEscape(thisFileNode.Value) + "');"
```

HtmlEscape method:

```
public static string HtmlEscape(string str)
    {
        return str
        .Replace("&", "&amp;")
        .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
        .Replace("'", "&#39;")
        .Replace("<", "&lt;")
        .Replace(">", "&gt;");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode:

```
      thisFileNode.NavigateUrl = "javascript:clickNode(this, '" + 
        HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(thisFileNode.Value) + "');"
```

Comment: Thanks onof, now am able to get the encoded value in my javascript... and how can i  decode that to orginal url without special charcters.

Comment: @ParvathiNair In Javascript use decodeURI. Server side you don't need decoding

Comment: Any tips for v2.0? `JavaScriptStringEncode` only comes to play in .NET v4.0.

Comment: @marquito you can use the decompiled version of that function: http://typedescriptor.net/browse/members/1341797-System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(String,Boolean)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can use `encodeURI(str)` to encode your URL or `encodeURIComponent(str)` to encode a part of it (such as a URL given as a component). More explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript).

Use `decodeURI(str)` and `decodeURIComponent(str)` to get the original string.

This thing is that those methods replace special characters that are forbidden in url into escape strings such as `&` becoming `&amp;`.

```
thisFileNode.NavigateUrl = 
    "javascript:clickNode(this, decodeURI('" + thisFileNode.Value + "'));"
```

Note: This is pertinent if `thisFileNode.Value` is a URL or is intended to be inserted into a URL.

What you might need is also (or instead) to escape quotes and so on which could be misinterpreted by javascript itself. I am not a .Net expert but `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode` should do the trick. You don't need to decode your string because it precisely allows you to set javascript string .